# Q: Highcharts #14 not showing chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i got error Uncaught Error: High charts error #14 and charts not showing.

```
showChart   @pricefeed:485
(anonymous) @ pricefeed:285
```

my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mf2x74qg/5/

Comment: Hi @user10459204, Could you explain your problem more precisely? The method: `Highcharts.StockChart` is not event fired in your example. Could you update your code?

Comment: click any Currency and Range
see Browser console not jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error points out: 'Highcharts expects numerical data values'. You need to parse your data to numbers, for example by:

```
    for(var i in data) {
        var timestamp = Date.parse(data[i]["tgl"]);
        series.data.push([timestamp, Number(data[i]["harga"])]);
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ax7nfjhL/